# stand alone matlab .exe cannot call functions successfully

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I designed a GUI and called some functions defined in CVX software package.(I have already installed the CVX software package). When running the .m file, the functions could be called successfully. However, if converting the .m file into  .exe, something went wrong, showing the following error message

> Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.
>   error cvx_global (line 76)
>   error cvxprob (line 4)
>   error cvx_begin (line 41)
>   Line 76 of cvx_global.m is:
>    osolvers = cvx___.solvers.list;

How can the problem be solved?

Comment: you have to include the other functions when you compile the code.  Add them to the dependencies

Comment: How to operate?